# A selinux permission problem occurs when android 13 adds a new service

Tags: selinux

1. Added a custom service, the service name is bean, the service is no problem, manually shutting down selinux can run normally.
2. Established vendor/jiangc/sepolicy in aosp

```
   vendor
   └── jiangc
       └── sepolicy
           ├── private
           │   └── service_contexts
           └── public
               ├── service.te
               └── system_server.te
```

The content is as follows:

```
service_contexts：
bean u:object_r:bean_service:s0

service.te
type bean_service, service_manager_type;

system_server.te
allow system_server bean_service:service_manager add;
```

Then modify the aosp/device/generic/car/emulator/aosp_car_emulator.mk file

At the end append the following:
BOARD_VENDOR_SEPOLICY_DIRS += vendor/jiangc/sepolicy

Then compile: source build/envsetup.sh
lunch sdk_car_x86-userdebug
Start the emulator emulator

Still error:
auditd  : avc:  denied  { add } for pid=831 uid=1000 name=bean scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:default_android_service:s0 tclass=service_manager permissive=0

I try make clean, recompile, it still doesn't work
Tried modifying to

```
BOARD_PLAT_PUBLIC_SEPOLICY_DIR += vendor/jiangc/sepolicy/public
BOARD_PLAT_PRIVATE_SEPOLICY_DIR += vendor/jiangc/sepolicy/private
BOARD_VENDOR_SEPOLICY_DIRS += vendor/jiangc/sepolicy
```

it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem seems to be solved, the first is that I accidentally changed the file name of service_contexts, and the second is that besides adding

```
BOARD_VENDOR_SEPOLICY_DIRS += vendor/jiangc/sepolicy
```

In addition to the mk file, you need to add the following code to the relevant mk

```
BOARD_PLAT_PUBLIC_SEPOLICY_DIR += vendor/jiangc/sepolicy/public
BOARD_PLAT_PRIVATE_SEPOLICY_DIR += vendor/jiangc/sepolicy/private
```

finally:

```
BOARD_PLAT_PUBLIC_SEPOLICY_DIR += vendor/jiangc/sepolicy/public
BOARD_PLAT_PRIVATE_SEPOLICY_DIR += vendor/jiangc/sepolicy/private
BOARD_VENDOR_SEPOLICY_DIRS += vendor/jiangc/sepolicy
```